# Create new pandas dataframe from rows with values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new data frame using only the rows from a another data frame (called "div" here) containing values in column 3, labeled "annum".

Then I would like to create a new column, labeled "growth", within the new data frame containing those values divided by the next row and 1 subtracted from the quotient. I am close but am not sure how to get what I need.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

```
def g_rate():

  div= dh()
  df= pd.DataFrame()

  for count in range(0,len(div)):
    if count == 0:

        df[count] = [div.iloc[0, 2]]

    if count >0:
        if count <10:
            
            row = count*3+count+3
            df[count] = [div.iloc[row, 2]]

  print(df)
```

The output:

```
Enter ticker: C
    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0 NaN  2.04  2.04  1.92  1.54  0.96  0.42  0.16  0.04  0.04
```

The desired output:

```
   Year  C_dividends  annum  growth
0  2022         0.51   2.04   0          #annum row 0/annum row 1
1  2021         0.51   2.04   0          #annum row 1/annum row 2
2  2020         0.51   2.04   0.0625     #annum row 2/annum row 3 and so on
3  2019         0.45   1.92   0.246753
4  2018         0.32   1.54   0.604167
5  2017         0.16   0.96   1.285714
6  2016         0.05   0.42   1.625
7  2015         0.01   0.16   3
8  2014         0.01   0.04   0
9  2013         0.01   0.04   NaN #or 0, as it is the last row
```

The div index:

```
           Date  C_dividends  annum
0   04 Nov 2022         0.51    NaN
1   29 Jul 2022         0.51    NaN
2   29 Apr 2022         0.51    NaN
3   04 Feb 2022         0.51   2.04
4   29 Oct 2021         0.51    NaN
5   30 Jul 2021         0.51    NaN
6   30 Apr 2021         0.51    NaN
7   29 Jan 2021         0.51   2.04
8   30 Oct 2020         0.51    NaN
9   31 Jul 2020         0.51    NaN
10  01 May 2020         0.51    NaN
11  31 Jan 2020         0.51   2.04
12  01 Nov 2019         0.51    NaN
13  02 Aug 2019         0.51    NaN
14  03 May 2019         0.45    NaN
15  01 Feb 2019         0.45   1.92
16  02 Nov 2018         0.45    NaN
17  03 Aug 2018         0.45    NaN
18  04 May 2018         0.32    NaN
19  02 Feb 2018         0.32   1.54
20  03 Nov 2017         0.32    NaN
21  03 Aug 2017         0.32    NaN
22  27 Apr 2017         0.16    NaN
23  02 Feb 2017         0.16   0.96
24  03 Nov 2016         0.16    NaN
25  28 Jul 2016         0.16    NaN
26  28 Apr 2016         0.05    NaN
27  28 Jan 2016         0.05   0.42
28  29 Oct 2015         0.05    NaN
29  30 Jul 2015         0.05    NaN
30  07 May 2015         0.05    NaN
31  29 Jan 2015         0.01   0.16
32  30 Oct 2014         0.01    NaN
33  31 Jul 2014         0.01    NaN
34  01 May 2014         0.01    NaN
35  30 Jan 2014         0.01   0.04
36  31 Oct 2013         0.01    NaN
37  01 Aug 2013         0.01    NaN
38  02 May 2013         0.01    NaN
39  31 Jan 2013         0.01   0.04
```

Comment: Filter out the NaN rows, then use shift() to get the previous year's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
df2 = df[ df['annum'].notnull() ].copy()

df2['growth'] = df['annum'] / df['annum'].shift(-1) - 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to reset the index? The index counts by 4's now, which will make it confusing down the road

Comment: I got it. `df.index= pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))`

Comment: @user14894283 I think it's faster to use `.reset_index(drop=True).copy()` in place of `.copy()` on line 1.

Comment: Thank you. How do you go about determining speed? I am a college student learning data sci, but they don't teach much python in my program. Is that just from experience?

Comment: @user14894283 Mostly experience, partly rules-of-thumb (heuristics); a single method call is usually faster (or no slower) than call to Index, then a call to len, then a call to RangeIndex, then an assignment to Index. To test, make a method you can call repeatedly and use `timeit.timeit()` to have python run it multiple times and calculate the average elapsed time for you.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using that twice after creating a function to derive an integer "maxv", which is 4 in this case. `div_g['growth_rate'] = div_g['growth'].groupby(div_g.index //maxv).sum()/maxv`. Do you know how I might skip 4 rows for each value in that column?

Comment: Or at least I thought I grabbed inspiration from this post, perhaps I read it elsewhere. When you say make a method, you mean make a script and call it from a loop in another or manually enter?

Comment: @user14894283 - I recommend asking a new question on SO, or just googling `python timeit`.  SO is not a chat based forum, we're about to get automated warnings about how many comments we're adding.  Also, this is reaching far outside the scope of your original question.  For now the short answer is `def some_method(): <yourCode>` and then `timeit.timeit(some_method())`